# What "happens" to the components of a composite quantum system?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space

Consider several separate systems described by their respective Hilbert spaces $\mathscr H_i$, a composite system $\mathscr{H=\bigotimes_i H_i}$ described by the tensor product of those Hilbert spaces, and the projectors $\widehat{p_i}:\mathscr{H\to H_i}$ from $\mathscr H$ back to its $\mathscr H_i$ components.

Each $\mathscr H_i$ subsystem is presumably a separately-existing measurable system in its own right. So we can separately and simultaneously measure/determine a pure (or mixed, but let's consider pure) state, say $\left|\psi_i\right>\in\mathscr H_i$ for each, with all $\left|\psi_i \right>\neq 0$. And then the corresponding composite pure state would presumably be a (renormalized) $\left|\psi\right>\in\mathscr H$ such that $\widehat{p_i}:\left|\psi\right>\to\left|\psi_i\right>$.

However, we can also measure the composite system itself, possibly obtaining a $\left|\psi\right>$ orthogonal to some of the $\mathscr H_i$, $\textit i.e.$,such that $\widehat p_i:\left|\psi\right>\to 0$ for some $i$. Indeed, consider the pvm observable $Q=\sum_i q_i\widehat{p_i}$ (with nondegenerate $q_i$) whose measurement results in some $q_i$ eigenvalue, whereby the composite system's state has no/zero component in any of the other subspaces.

So what "happens" to these other component subsystems in such a situation? It seems like they have to be described by a $\left|0\right>$ state, more or less meaning they don't exist. But it's these components that originally physically existed in the first place. It's just an idea in our heads to consider them as a single composite system. When the $\mathscr H_i$ are just subspaces of $\mathscr H$, not themselves associated with any separate physical systems, this isn't (I don't think) a problem. But it seems very problematic when they're the originally-given and separately-existing components of a composite system constructed from them.